# scipy.optimize.minimize Error when calling to scipy.sparse.csr_matrix

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, sparse-matrix, minimize

I'm trying to use scipy.optimize.minimize in the filowing way:

> fi = minimize( fun=quadratic_function , x0=fi, args=(  alfa, Ks, Kf), method='Nelder-Mead' ).x

where fi is the parameter to be optimizated. And quadratic_function is in such nature that in every call, should construct a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix. So, among other errors I get this (sorry for mixing spanish and english names):

> File "/Users/angel/Dropbox/Intercambio CIMAT/Solver/V2/sistemas/explicito.py", line 56, in solver_explicito
>       Matriz_Biot_strain = esfuerzos_biot( malla, factor, P, Q, R, N )
>
> File "/Users/angel/Dropbox/Intercambio CIMAT/Solver/V2/sistemas/sigma_biot.py", line 172, in esfuerzos_biot
>       sistema = csr_matrix( (vals,(rows,cols) )  ,shape = ( 4*Nodes, 4*Nodes ), dtype=np.float64 )
>
> File "/Users/angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 48, in **init**
>       other = self.**class**(coo_matrix(arg1, shape=shape))
>
> File "/Users/angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 31, in **init**
>       arg1 = arg1.asformat(self.format)
>
> File "/Users/angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 213, in asformat
>       return getattr(self,'to' + format)()
>
> File "/Users/angel/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 362, in tocsr
>       data)
>
> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('bool') according to the rule 'safe'

I tried to make

> fi = np.asarray(fi,dtype=np.float64)

But without success.

P.S. In can evaluate quadratic_function(fi,alfa, Ks, Kf), which is a scalar value

Edit:

For future refference, I was able to solve the problem just by casting my variables to float in every call to quadratic_function, i.e. by doing the following:

> fi = float(fi)

On the other hand, for the sake of completeness of the problem:
@hpaulj in this particular problem, Nodes = 151452, but it can grow since I'm solving a FEM problem. And because it's a FEM problem, the matrix is to much sparse. Finally, I was not able to find any documentation relating the ussage of minimize and then calling to scypy sparse.

Comment: I doubt if `minimize` is designed to work with `sparse` matrices. Have you seen any documentation supporting that use?  Better return the dense equivalent (`.toarray()` or `.A`).  How large are these sparse matrices? How sparse?

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to have to do with optimize.minimize actually. Rather, it looks like inside quadratic_function, you are trying to construct a sparse matrix in some wrong way. Impossible to say what exactly, since you do not show the code. Use the [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to find out what goes wrong.